# Can I use multiple if statement in with with same validation?

Tags: 8, theming

Multiple if statement with similar validation will crash(WSOD) my website and I'm not sure if this an expected behavior, meaning what I'm doing is wrong. Or this is a bug, which I should fill into Drupal.org as bug.

Here is my code.

```
  {%  if page.footer_second and page.footer_third %}
       {% set col_class = 'six' %}

   {# If we have 3 columns#}
   {%  if page.footer_first and page.footer_second and page.footer_third %}
       {% set col_class = 'four' %}

   {# If we have 2 columns#}
   {%  elseif page.footer_first or page.footer_first or footer_third %}
        {% set col_class = 'eight' %}
   {% else %}
        {% set col_class = 'ten' %}
   {% endif %}


   <div class="{{ col_class }} columns">   
     {{ page.footer_first }}
   </div>

    <div class="{{ col_class }} columns">
     {{ page.footer_second }}
     </div>
     <div class="{{ col_class }} columns">
         {{ page.footer_third }}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```

If I remove one of my if statement my website will not crash (WSOD).

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: did you check apache error log. multiple if statement is perfectly supported by Twig. It seems you have some problem with variables if they are not defined.

Comment: Can you provide the whole template? Nothing looks out of the ordinary other than what Cottser posted, but still this shouldn't cause WSOD. D8 Twig has strict variable checking off by default.

Comment: I am using foundation so i can use numbers and so i set up the maximum width and then check for columns and decrease the max width accordingly. Like set content_width = 12, if page.left set content_width = content_width - 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating the `set col_class` conditions from the display condition. Something like this...

```
{# first, set the col_class #}
{% if page.footer_second and page.footer_second and page.footer_third %}
    {% set col_class = 'four' %}
{% elseif page.footer_first and page.footer_third %}
    {% set col_class = 'six' %}
{% elseif page.footer_first or page.footer_second or page.footer_third %}
    {% set col_class = 'eight' %}
{% else %}
    {% set col_class = 'ten' %}
{% endif %}

{# then, display the columns #}
{% if col_class %}
   <div class="{{ col_class }} columns">   
     {{ page.footer_first }}
   </div>
   <div class="{{ col_class }} columns">
     {{ page.footer_second }}
   </div>
   <div class="{{ col_class }} columns">
     {{ page.footer_third }}
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

You could (should?) probably set that `col_class` var in a preprocess hook to get all those ifs out of the template

Answer (score 2):

What's jumping out at me is this line:

```
elseif page.footer_first or page.footer_first or footer_third
```

It's checking `page.footer_first` twice, and `footer_third`, which based on the code you've shown is not a valid variable, it should be `page.footer_third`. I'm guessing this should be more like:

```
elseif page.footer_first or page.footer_second or page.footer_third
```

Comment: Actually, I fixed that an still not been able to the another two `if` statements.